# How we can show a custom popup in table view controller in swift language

Tags: swift

How we can show a custom view popup in table view controller when we click a table cell in Swift programming language ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath tableview delegate method just like in Objective-C

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Sample Popup", message: "You clicked cell at index : \(indexPath!.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)        
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))        
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Make sure you have inherited the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate at your class definition. I've given a sample snippet

```
class SampleTableViewController : UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

// data source and delegate methods....

}
```

Use this...

Comment: FYI: "UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate" is redundant in Swift2 or Xcode 7